# linux memory management - how to get "Random xxx offset"?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am studying process memory management.

I read a post about **Process address space layout.**

I referenced the following [URL.](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/)

[image: processMemlayout]

In linux, start_data, end_data, start_brk, brk, etc are member variable of struct mm_struct.

However I want to know how to calculate **Random brk, stack, mmap offset.**

It seems that those three values(Random xxx offset) are't defined in struct mm_struct.

Is there any function or MACRO to calculate those values?

I am using linux kernel version 4.4 and x86-64 architecture.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to know where the segments are for your process, or how to calculate random numbers? Once the process is created, they are fixed. The randomization is just to make it harder to hack, so the hacker doesn't know exactly where to look to read things from your stack or heap.

Comment: @e0k thanks for your kind comment. I want to know where the segments are.

For example, code segment exists between start_code and end_code.
Also data segment exists between start_data and end_data.

I want to know about Bss segment. **Bss segment starts at end_data.** However I don't know where Bss segment ends.

Comment: @newbie16  The BSS is not stored in any particular variable of the kernel, but there is a VMA allocated for the corresponding location.

Comment: The kernel lists the memory mappings for the current process in pseudo-file `/proc/self/maps`. It is not a real file; it does not "exist" on disk or anywhere else, but is generated by the kernel as needed, when read. If you add reading and printing that to your program, and run it (or just `cat /proc/self/maps`) repeatedly, you can see that the address of the base code stays fixed, but the mappings for the libraries, stack, and heap do vary. (Also, the image shown does not apply to x86-64 architecture.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal thank you for your comment. I want to see real kernel code how Bss segment address is calculated.
Code snippet I seek does not seem to exist in `/fs/proc/self.c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OS already implements /proc/< pid >/maps which shows all VMAs of that process, including the stack,heap and of course the mmap-ed ones.

If you want to check from where all these information fill you can check kernel source code, the relevant code (to look up VMAs of a given PID) seems to be here: **fs/proc/task_mmu.c** .

And, yes indeed, the "[heap]" is marked by this code snippet from the above src file (kernel ver 3.10.24):

**fs/proc/task_mmu.c:show_map_vma()**

```
... 
if (vma->vm_start <= mm->brk && vma->vm_end >= mm->start_brk) 
{ 
    name = "[heap]"; goto done; } 
...
```

And one more thing if you want to check start-end address of particular segment, Do check The mm_struct is defined in . you will get following thing :-

```
struct mm_struct{
......
    unsigned long start_code, end_code, start_data, end_data;
    unsigned long start_brk, brk, start_stack;
......
}
```

1. start_code, end_code The start and end address of the code section;
2. start_data, end_data The start and end address of the data section;
3. start_brk, brk The start and end address of the heap;
4. start_stack Predictably enough, the start of the stack region;